# Given $x-\sqrt {\dfrac {8}{x}}=9$, what is $x-\sqrt{8x}$ equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, factoring, substitution

> Given $x-\sqrt {\dfrac {8}{x}}=9$, what is $x-\sqrt{8x}$ equal to?

**My attempt:**
We have
\begin{align}
x-\sqrt {\dfrac {8}{x}}=9
\implies -\sqrt {\dfrac {8}{x}}=9-x
\implies \dfrac {8}{x}=(9-x)^2
\end{align}

How can I proceed?

Comment: You are given $$x-\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{x}} = 9$$ Subtract 9 from both sides and add $$\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{x}}$$ to both sides. This gives:  $$\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{x}} = x-9$$ Next, square both sides. Now you have: $$\dfrac{8}{x} = (x-9)^2$$ Multiply both sides by $x$ and multiply out: $$8 = x^3-18x^2+81x$$ Subtract 8 from both sides and factor: $$x^3-18x^2+81x-8 = 0 \Longrightarrow (x-8)(x^2-10x+1) = 0$$ This implies either $x=8$ or $x^2-10x+1=0 \Longrightarrow x=5\pm \sqrt{24}$. Plug in each possible solution and find only $x=5+\sqrt{24}$ works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with what you have written we quickly see that $$0=x^3-18x^2+81x-8=(x-8)(x^2-10x+1)$$

It is easy to see that $x\neq 8$ so we must have $\boxed {x^2-10x+1=0}$

Now, go back to the original equation.  Multiply by $x$ to get $$x^2-\sqrt {8x}=9x\implies x-\sqrt {8x}=10x-x^2$$

But the boxed equation tells us that $10x-x^2=1$ so $$\boxed {x-\sqrt {8x}=1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=t^2,$ where $t>0$.

Thus, $$t^3-9t-\sqrt8=0$$ or
$$t^3+\sqrt8t^2-\sqrt8t^2-8t-t-\sqrt8=0$$ or
$$(t+\sqrt8)(t^2-\sqrt8t-1)=0$$ or
$$x-\sqrt{8x}=1.$$

Comment: In place of artificial $(\sqrt8-\sqrt8)t^2$ we clearly use $t+a$ is a factor of $$t^3-(a^2+1)t-a$$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee In my opinion it's the same, even your way a bit of complicated.

Answer (score 0):

$x-\dfrac {\sqrt {8x}}{x}=9,\Rightarrow x^{2}-\sqrt {8x}=9x$
$\begin{aligned}x^{2}-9x=\sqrt {8x}\\ x^{2}-8x=\sqrt {8x}+x\\ \left( x-\sqrt {8x}\right) \left( x+\sqrt {8x}\right) =\sqrt {8x}+x\\ x -\sqrt {8x}=1\end{aligned}$